# Anagram counter

Tags: algorithm, strings, scala, homework

Homework prompt was:

> You are given two strings, a ‘parent’ string and a ‘query’ string respectively. Your task is  to determine how many times the query string – or an anagram of the query string  appears in the parent string.
>
> NOTE: There are a range of solutions to this problem. With a little thought, you can 
>   massively improve the efficiency of your solution. The optimal solution runs almost 
>   instantly even for extremely large (1 million+ characters) parent and query strings.
>
> #### Sample Input
>
> ```
> AdnBndAndBdaBn
> dAn
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output
>
> ```
> 4
> ```
>
> #### Explanation
>
> The substrings are highlighted below.
>
> - `AdnBndAndBdaBn`
> - `AdnBndAndBdaBn`
> - `AdnBndAndBdaBn`
> - `AdnBndAndBdaBn`

---

It had to take input from keyboard and print to stdout. My solution was to "slide" a window picking up *N*, where *N* == query string length and counting char frequency to determine if that bit is an anagram. 
I did it in Scala, but I feel it could be improved. Any pointers?

My code:

```
object AnagramDetection {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val input = io.StdIn.readLine()
    val query = io.StdIn.readLine()
    println(anagramCount(input, query))
  }

  def anagramCount(input: String, query: String): Int = {
    var count = 0
    if(query.length < input.length) {

      val keyMap = (str: String) =>  str.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
      val keyCount = keyMap(query)
      for(start <- 0 until input.length - query.length) {
        if(keyMap(input.substring(start, start + query.length)) == keyCount) {
          count += 1
        }
      }

    }
    count
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop should be replaced by [`input.sliding(query.length)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@sliding(size:Int,step:Int):Iterator[Repr]).

The `if (…) { count += 1 }` statement should be replaced by [`count(predicate)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@count(p:A=>Boolean):Int).

If performance is a concern, you should be able to avoid re-evaluating `keyMap` from scratch for each window, by using the previous `keyMap` and decrementing and incrementing the counts of the characters at the margins.